# Same hostname but different path with Let's Encrypt

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, lets-encrypt

I've configured Let's Encrypt using cert-manager in my cluster and it works just fine for most of my use cases. However I have an application which is installed multiple times on the same hostname but with a different path.

My ingress is defined as below

```
{{- if .Values.ingress.enabled -}}
{{- $fullName := include "whoami-go.fullname" . -}}
{{- $svcPort := .Values.service.port -}}
{{- $tls := hasKey .Values.ingress "certIssuer" -}}
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ $fullName }}
  labels:
    {{- include "whoami-go.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  annotations:
  {{- if $tls }}
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: {{ .Values.ingress.certIssuer | quote }}
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
  {{- end }}
spec:
  {{- if $tls }}
  tls:
    - secretName: {{ $fullName }}-tls
      hosts:
        - {{ .Values.ingress.hostname | quote }}
  {{- end }}
  rules:
    - host: {{ .Values.ingress.hostname | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: {{ .Values.ingress.path }}
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: {{ $fullName }}
                port:
                  number: {{ $svcPort }}
{{- end }}
```

And it's instantiated with values like below

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  hostname: whoami-go.c.dhis2.org
  path: /something
  certIssuer: letsencrypt-prod
```

Where `path` is changed for each installation.

The problem...

```
E0520 03:13:49.242770 1 sync.go:210] cert-manager/controller/orders "msg"="failed to create Order resource due to bad request, marking Order as failed" "error"="429 urn:ietf:params:acme:error:rateLimited: Error creating new order :: too many certificates already issued for exact set of domains: whoami-go.c.dhis2.org: see https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/" "resource_kind"="Order" "resource_name"="finland-whoami-go-tls-tzvk6-4169341110" "resource_namespace"="whoami" "resource_version"="v1"
```

Since only the path is updated I hoped that cert-manager would reuse the certificate but that's obviously not the case. Can I somehow configure my application to use the same certificate for the same hostname across multiple installations of the same chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error meaning

```
urn:ietf:params:acme:error:rateLimited: Error creating new order :: too many certificates already issued for exact set of domains: whoami-go.c.dhis2.org:
```

we can only request a certain amount of SSL/TLS certificate from the let's encrypt in week.

Read more at : https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/

Due to that, it's showing the error of the rate-limiting. We can request for the 5 cert per week for duplicate cert.

you are using the **certIssuer: letsencrypt-prod** or cluster issuer which will be storing the secret into the **Kubernetes secret**.

While creating the ingress with different paths just change secret or add the secret to ingress as per need your ingress will be working with HTTPS.

while keep only one ingress with cluster issuer or issuer so if certificate getting explored it can auto-renew in to secret and that secret will be used by other ingress.

my simple ingress with he **SSL/TLS** cert stored into secret.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: sls-dev
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "15m"
  name: sls-function-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: app.dev.example.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/v1/
        backend:
          serviceName: test-service
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - app.dev.example.io
    secretName: sls-secret
```

you can keep `cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: sls-dev` to one ingress while with other only **secret** need to attach.

Comment: Yes, I got that part. That's why I want to make cert-manager reuse the existing certificate if the hostname is the same.

Comment: @user672009 above shared example ingress also you can use secret in it. to reuse existing cert you can just use the existing secret in which it's storing cert

Comment: The key to this was using the same name for the secret. In my case I named it the same as the hostname. That way cert manager won't make multiple request to Let's Encrypt for the same hostname